# WTP Server set to WebLogic Server instead of Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-wtp

i've created a Maven project, after doing mvn eclipse:eclipse, sets the WTP Server to WebLogic instead of Tomcat, tried to search how to change this! but i couldn't find a solution as of yet! Installed the Oracle WebLogic few hours ago and Tomcat, don't know why is setting that WTP.

Do you know how to change this or set it up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove weblogic from your hdd with eclipse settings or turn it off
you'll need a couple free port numbers for example 8080, 8009, 8005
ofcourse it's depends by you, but if you wish work without troubles in the future my advice 
is as I wrote :D

after this one, download tomcat from:

http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

version: 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer (pgp, md5)

Install it in eclipse folder as TOMCAT7 and set up server in ecpipse environment
this is the best way I know to have couple of tomcat (if you will have netbeans, eclipse maybe even a 3 or more instantiation and every one with different tomcat or other server to check it how it works)

I assume that you know some basics of setting up server if you dont know much about it dont be afraid to asking, cuz at the begining it can be a little confusing and sometimes annoying

and dont run 2 server at the same port at the same time - it cant work out

and btw you dont need to setting up any of classpath or system variables only follow as I told you

here you can check it out :

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html

you will need only to show the eclise the right path to your tomcat instalation (as I wrote make it in eclipse folder - it will remaind you it's not for remove or change :D)